# References about develop a web application which supports large numbers of concurrent users

Tags: c#, java, performance

We got a project which need to develop a web application that supports large numbers of concurrent users(around 5000).
This application mainly used for submit application, business process management. So it is not just an informational website.
We developed similar application before (use spring + hibernate + jsf), but after more users involved, the performance will drop dramatically.
My question is what architecture should I consider, what kind of hardware should we consider? Is there any references( books, blogs, websites ) which I can use to start my research and find out a better architecture for this new project ?

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Comment: I think it more about the hardware question the more users the more operation the server need to handle the more bandwidths, speed ans so on you need

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you specific references, but if you go to your favourite online bookstore, and search on "building scalable websites", there are a number of books on the subject.

(I wouldn't worry too much about publication dates because the principles haven't changed radically in the last few years.)

There are also a few past questions on SO whose answers offer good advice.  However, this is too large a topic for S) Q&A's to cover adequately.  Hence a text book is better.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Scalable Internet Architectures](http://amzn.to/myfMn1) by Theo Schlossnagle and [The Art of Scalability](http://amzn.to/jG2AzI) by Abbott and Fisher they are both very good boxes and will take you through the principles